# Composite primary key mySQL

Tags: mysql

Im doing a project in the school, where i ran into an issue with my composite primary keys..

when im defining my composite primary keys, i type in the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `Product Shipment` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(Product_code,Shipment_ID)
```

mySQL is returning with following error:

**#1832 - Cannot change column 'Shipment_ID': used in a foreign key constraint 'Shipment_ID'**

Im then trying to remove my following key by:

```
alter table `product Shipment` drop constraint `Shipment_ID`
```

Where im getting a random error,

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'constraint `Shipment_ID`' at line 1**

Im pretty new to this, and dont seem to get how i will do this the right way.. :s

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using your Shipment_ID as foreign Key?

Comment: Will not solve your current problem but please don't use a space in table and column names

Comment: You are not able to drop the primary key as it is used as a reference in some other table(foreign key)

Comment: In cases where you don't need to rebuild your constraint, simply use the `foreign_key_checks` system variable to temporarily turn off the checks.

Answer (score 1):

For dropping the foreign key constraint you can use the following

```
ALTER TABLE `product Shipment` DROP FOREIGN KEY `Shipment_ID`;
```

Comment: wow.. that worked with charm!!! thank you very much, now i can sleep well tonight :D